# remove class but not selector class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove class from div but selector class like: I want to remove only 'check' from below div.

Note: class name are dynamic. Its name can be anything.

```
<div class="pop check"></div>
$(function(){
$('.pop').not('pop').removeClass()  // not working
})
```

working code

```
$(function(){
$('.pop').removeClass().addClass('pop')
})
```

Is there any better way to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery removeClass() to remove all classes but one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322225/using-jquery-removeclass-to-remove-all-classes-but-one) as well as [Remove all classes except one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363289/remove-all-classes-except-one) etc.

Comment: Answer here .. [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)`:p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your class by:

```
$(function() {
    $('.pop').removeClass('check')
});
```

Comment: Seeing [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) might have been less time costing `:p`

Comment: Isn't the classname "check" dynamic, so it could be anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('.pop').attr('class','pop');
```

Comment: +1. This would be better if all classes except the selector class needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($(".pop").attr("class")!="pop"){
   $(".pop").attr("class","").addClass('pop');//to remove all classes and add pop class
}
```

Comment: what if <div class="pop check"></div>

Comment: @amit upadated ans thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just write it as:

```
$(".pop").removeClass("check");
```

Comment: *Hint: If you append 4 spaces or a tab in the front of code, it is formatted as a code box.*

Comment: @h2ooooooo: I edited and was just about to post the same comment :)

Comment: I of course mean "prepend" btw! :) It doesn't make much sense to "append" stuff in "front" of something.