# How to add one class at a time and remove previously added classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add only **selected class** and **remove other class** which is selected before?

```
<html>
    <select name="Button-Style" id="Button-Style" style="width:100%;">

     <option value="Sun-Flower">Sun Flower</option>
     <option value="orange-flat">orange-flat</option>


   </select>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Button-Style').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 'sun-flower'){
             $("#$id>input").addClass('sun-flower-button');
              }
          else if($(this).val() == 'orange-flat'){
             $("#" + id).addClass('orange-flat-button');
              }



          else{

              }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

I want to add only one class at a time.

Comment: Can you explain more about your porpouse and show example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all classes except one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363289/remove-all-classes-except-one)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to selection of element on which you are adding class but you can use [**removeClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) without supplying parameter to function to remove all previously applied class to item and then add your class as you are doing using `addClass()`

```
   if($(this).val() == 'sun-flower'){
       $("#$id>input").removeClass(); // Remove all classes .. although please check selector 
       $("#$id>input").addClass('sun-flower-button');
         }
          else if($(this).val() == 'orange-flat'){
              $("#" + id).removeClass();
             $("#" + id).addClass('orange-flat-button');
              }
```

Also may I suggest passing class name directly from option values in select item. Then no need for extra if condition .

```
<select name="Button-Style" id="Button-Style" style="width:100%;">
     <option value="Sun-Flower-button">Sun Flower</option>
     <option value="orange-flat-button">orange-flat</option>
</select>
```

and in jquery

```
$('#Button-Style').change(function(){
  var className = $(this).val();
  $('#inputElement').removeClass();
  $('#inputElement').addClass(className);        
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1424991/3274964).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with jquery.

```
            $('.selected_check').change(function () {

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    var x = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
                    var id = "#" + x;
                    $(id).removeClass('td_bgcolor');
                    $(id).addClass('highlight_row');
                } else {
                    var y = $(this).closest('tr').prop('id');
                    var id = "#" + y;
                    $(id).removeClass('highlight_row');
                    $(id).addClass('td_bgcolor');
                }

            });
```

simply use removeClass and addClass cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove all previous classes and add a new one, you can use jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp) function.

Answer (score 0):

Use removeClass() function in jQuery.

As for example;

HTML:

```
<div id="adiv" class="1st-class"></div>
```

Now jQuery;

```
$("#adiv").addClass("2nd-div");             // This 'll add 2nd-class with the div

$("#adiv").removeClass("1st-div");          //This 'll remove the 1st-class from the div.
```

Now if you want to remove all previous added class simply do;

```
$("#adiv").removeClass();                   //removeClass without any argument removes all class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty understanding your question, but I think I get the gist of it.

Say you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu--option">Option 1</div>
  <div class="menu--option">Option 2</div>
  <div class="menu--option">Option 3</div>
</div>
```

Whenever someone clicks on an option, we want to add the class `s-active` to it, while making sure it is the only one with that class. You will want to do something like this:

```
// First, we listen to the click event.
$("menu--option").click(function () {

  // When it fires, we select all of the menu options,
  // and iterate over them, removing '.s-active' from it
  // if the element has the class.
  $("menu--option").each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("s-active");
  });

  // Finally, we add '.s-active' to the element that was clicked.
  $(this).addClass("s-active");
}
```

Hopefully this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can code it in this way!

```
 $('#Button-Style').change(function(){
$(this).removeClass();
if($(this).val()=="your_option_value"){
$(this).addClass("new_class");}
}
```