# Remove all classes except one in Javascript on mouseleave

Tags: javascript

I Want to Remove all class except dpkCursor

```
<div class="dpkCursor active disk"></div>
```

I'm reseting it on mouseenter

```
   target.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetCursor);


   function resetCursor() {

     //  dpkCursor.classList.remove("active");

         dpkCursor.className = ""
         dpkCursor.classList.add(dpkCursor); // bad approach 
           
   }
```

I dont want to remove this class like this as because its
breaking my css and cause flickers
just remove all class except this
What is the best way to do so

Comment: _"What is the best way to do so"_ - which ever way you write it that works and is easy to maintain.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach...

Comment: What is the issue with the way you did it?  `dpkCursor.className = 'dpkCursor'` is one less step. Do you know what classes are added?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363289/remove-all-classes-except-one

Comment: So just do `dpkCursor.className = 'dpkCursor'`...... no different than what you accepted other than `dpkCursor` is not hard coded. If you know what classes could be added `dpkCursor.classList.remove("foo", "bar", "baz");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use also `split` function:

```
 target.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetCursor);


   function resetCursor() {
         dpkCursor.className = dpkCursor.className.split(' ')[0];
   }
```

This will set `dpkCursor.className` to first class (dpkCursor)

Comment: hopefully the class is zero position....

Comment: Not sure how it is anymore better than just doing `dpkCursor.className = 'dpkCursor'` lol

Comment: Yes, this answer is literally `dpkCursor.className = 'dpkCursor'` only thing is to get `dpkCursor` is it parsing the string....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove everything, the easiest thing is just set it back to the start

```
dpkCursor.className = 'dpkCursor';
```

If you know what classes could have been added, you can just remove them. If they are not there, it makes no difference. So just put all the classes that could be there in the remove method.

```
dpkCursor.classList.remove('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Comment: @Dpk as long as you think it will always be first, then risk it. Hopefully something does not alter the order in the future. :)

Comment: @epascarello because you're not doing it _exactly how the OP wants_, even if your answer is simpler. Maybe they need it to be dynamic, but then that should be specified in the question.

Comment: In the end, my guess is whatever you are doing could be done 100% in CSS and would not even need this.